# Using multiple progress bars in tqdm in vscode's jupyter notebook interface

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter, tqdm

When running two progress bars from tqdm, I get repeated lines in a Jupyter Notebook, running in visual studio code's juypter notebook interface:

```
from tqdm.auto import tqdm
from time import sleep
bar1 = tqdm(total=100, position=0, dynamic_ncols=True, leave=True, unit='file', desc="hi 1", bar_format='{l_bar}{bar}| {n_fmt}/{total_fmt} [{elapsed}]')
bar2 = tqdm(total=100, position=1, dynamic_ncols=True, leave=True, unit='file', desc="hi 2", bar_format='{l_bar}{bar}| {n_fmt}/{total_fmt} [{elapsed}]')
for i in range(100):
    bar1.update(int(1))
    bar2.update(int(1))
    sleep(0.001)
```

The output I get looks like this:

```
hi 1:   0%|          | 0/100 [00:00]
hi 1:   7%|▋         | 7/100 [00:00]
hi 1:  14%|█▍        | 14/100 [00:00]
hi 1:  21%|██        | 21/100 [00:00]
hi 1:  28%|██▊       | 28/100 [00:00]
hi 1:  36%|███▌      | 36/100 [00:00]
hi 1:  43%|████▎     | 43/100 [00:00]
hi 1:  51%|█████     | 51/100 [00:00]
hi 1:  58%|█████▊    | 58/100 [00:00]
hi 1:  65%|██████▌   | 65/100 [00:01]
hi 1:  72%|███████▏  | 72/100 [00:01]
hi 1:  79%|███████▉  | 79/100 [00:01]
hi 1:  86%|████████▌ | 86/100 [00:01]
hi 1:  93%|█████████▎| 93/100 [00:01]
hi 1: 100%|██████████| 100/100 [00:01]
hi 2: 100%|██████████| 100/100 [00:01]A
```

If I instead do a single loop:

```
from tqdm.auto import tqdm
from time import sleep
bar1 = tqdm(total=100, position=0, dynamic_ncols=True, leave=True, unit='file', desc="hi 1", bar_format='{l_bar}{bar}| {n_fmt}/{total_fmt} [{elapsed}]')
for i in range(100):
    bar1.update(int(1))
    sleep(0.001)
```

Then the output is closer to what I expected:

```
hi 1:  94%|█████████▍| 94/100 [00:01]
```

Version information:
python: 3.9.6
vscode: 1.58.2
Python extension: v2021.7.1060902895
Jupyter Extension: v2021.8.1054968649

Comment: have you looked at the source code to see how such a bar is shown, and if that allows multiple progress bars

Comment: If you are asking "does this work in a terminal window" - yes, it does. You can test this by pasting the code into a file, and then running file via python. It also works if you force it to use the notebook extensions (ipywidgets).

Comment: I tried a console version and I am impressed it can handle multiple bars. looking at the code, there is a special `tqdm.notebook` have you tried that, but in `tqdm.autonotebook` it looks like VSCODE is not supported

Comment: I believe `tqdm` is designed to support many many simultaneous bars. And if I understand the logic correctly in `tqdm.notebook` that you are referring to, what isn't supported there are the jupyter notebook interfaces in vscode. The exception you are referring to just triggers the console (the logic is "odd" since it uses an exception. I could be reading the code incorrectly, of course! Modern vscode has support for the ipywigets, so that should probably get changed, but that is an issue independent from the one in this question, I think.

Comment: if it works with the ipywidgets then there auto import logic might be failing, I have seen imports for ipywidgets in the tqdm.auto... modules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have `ipywidgets` installed ([pip package](https://pypi.org/project/ipywidgets/)), then it works just fine:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You are correct - there were some fixes to vscode at some point and this now works as expected (or fixes to tqdm, not sure).

Comment: When posting code pleaase paste code instead of screenshots so others can copy it. Additionally please specify if ipywidgets is a pip package or a VScode extension.

Comment: The purpose of the screenshot was to illustrate how the progress bars look, not posting code (you can copy the code from the question). `ipywidgets` is a pip package, clarified.